# SEO-friendly URL rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Before you flag this question -- I did search for answers, and found one close to mine that was not answered directly, so...

I  am trying to write a simple RewriteRule in my .htaccess file to change ONLY the links that match to an SEO-friendly format.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/includes/seo.([a-zA-Z]+).php$ /$1
```

So if I have a file

```
/includes/seo.mydocument.php
```

it will appear in the browser as

```
/mydocument
```

Not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leading slash is not matched in .htaccess rules so use this

```
RewriteRule ^includes/seo\.([a-zA-Z]+)\.php$ /$1 [L,R]
```

But probably you want this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+includes/seo\.([^.]+)\.php[/\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /includes/seo.$1.php [L]
```

Comment: see edited code and make sure it is in document root .htaccess

Comment: It worked! Wow, a lot more complicated than I anticipated... Thanks.